# What's the difference between a POST and a PUT HTTP REQUEST?

Tags: http, post, put

They both seem to be sending data to the server inside the body, so what makes them different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PUT vs. POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Answer (score 1011, accepted):

**HTTP PUT:**

PUT puts a file or resource at a specific URI, and exactly at that URI. If there's already a file or resource at that URI, PUT replaces that file or resource.  If there is no file or resource there, PUT creates one. PUT is [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-idempotent-methods), but paradoxically PUT responses are not cacheable.

[HTTP 1.1 RFC location for PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-put)

**HTTP POST:**

POST sends data to a specific URI and expects the resource at that URI to handle the request.  The web server at this point can determine what to do with the data in the context of the specified resource. The POST method is not [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-idempotent-methods), however POST responses *are* cacheable so long as the server sets the appropriate Cache-Control and Expires headers.

The official HTTP RFC specifies POST to be:

- Annotation of existing resources;
- Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list,
  or similar group of articles;
- Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a
  form, to a data-handling process;
- Extending a database through an append operation.

[HTTP 1.1 RFC location for POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-post)

**Difference between POST and PUT:**

The RFC itself explains the core difference:

> The fundamental difference between the
> POST and PUT requests is reflected in
> the different meaning of the
> Request-URI. The URI in a POST request
> identifies the resource that will
> handle the enclosed entity. That
> resource might be a data-accepting
> process, a gateway to some other
> protocol, or a separate entity that
> accepts annotations. In contrast, the
> URI in a PUT request identifies the
> entity enclosed with the request --
> the user agent knows what URI is
> intended and the server MUST NOT
> attempt to apply the request to some
> other resource. If the server desires
> that the request be applied to a
> different URI, it MUST send a 301 (Moved Permanently) response; the user agent MAY then make
> its own decision regarding whether or not to redirect the request.

Additionally, and a bit more concisely, [RFC 7231 Section 4.3.4 PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) states (emphasis added),

> **4.3.4.  PUT**
>
> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be
> `created` or `replaced` with the state defined by the representation
> enclosed in the request message payload.

**Using the right method, unrelated aside:**

One benefit of [REST ROA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_oriented_architecture) vs SOAP is that when using HTTP REST ROA, it encourages the proper usage of the HTTP verbs/methods.  So for example you would only use PUT when you want to create a resource at that exact location.  And you would never use GET to create or modify a resource.

Comment: I read in the specs that `If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource [...] the origin server *can* create the resource with that URI`. So an implementation of PUT that refuses to create a resource if not present would be correct, right? If so, does this happen in practice? Or implementations usually also create on PUT?

Comment: some additional exception which makes the difference very clear is at next URL - https://dzone.com/articles/put-vs-post

Comment: What I don't understand is how to implement the idempotency of PUT. in general, most API's will be using auto generation of an ID in case of creating a new resource. and in PUT, you should create a resource if it doesn't exists, but use the ID specified in the URI, but how can you do that if the id generation method is set to be automatic ???

Comment: So in a nutshell: The URI in a **POST** request identifies **the resource that will handle the enclosed entity**. The URI in a **PUT** request identifies **the entity itself**.

Comment: Responses to POST method are not cacheable, UNLESS the response includes appropriate Cache-Control or Expires header fields

Comment: There are also some security-related differences: see my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request/55382661#55382661)

Comment: @RoniAxelrad I was wondering about this myself. But I think the idea is that you should never create a duplicate resource ever. So for example if you wanted to store a transaction as a "resource" using http://api.example.com/payments and the body of 2 requests are exactly the same, why are you storing them both and generating unique primary keys? Are you possible processing duplicate **requests**? Should you maybe reconsider your design?

Comment: Re: _"paradoxically PUT responses are not cacheable"_. Perhaps worth expanding the paradox that what **can be cacheable in PUTs are REQUESTs**: The 2014's RFC 7231 (one of RFCs that obsolete the 1999's RFC 2616) mentions [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) that PUT `allows a user agent to know when the representation body it has in memory remains current`, i.e. the server `MUST NOT send ... an ETag or Last-Modified ... unless the request's representation was saved without any transformation`.There may not be many clients with such cache but the servers should follow spec.

Answer (score 241):

Only semantics.

An HTTP `PUT` is supposed to accept the body of the request, and then store that at the resource identified by the URI.

An HTTP `POST` is more general.  It is supposed to initiate an action on the server.  That action could be to store the request body at the resource identified by the URI, or it could be a different URI, or it could be a different action.

PUT is **like** a file upload.  A put to a URI affects exactly that URI.  A POST to a URI could have any effect at all.

Comment: That which implies a certain function may not actually

Answer (score 156):

To give examples of REST-style resources:

`POST /books` with a bunch of book information might create a new book, and respond with the new URL identifying that book: `/books/5`.

`PUT /books/5` would have to either create a new book with the ID of 5, or replace the existing book with ID 5.

In non-resource style, `POST` can be used for just about anything that has a side effect. One other difference is that `PUT` should be idempotent: multiple `PUT`s of the same data to the same URL should be fine, whereas multiple `POST`s might create multiple objects or whatever it is your `POST` action does.

Comment: Hi Bhollis, What will happen, if I use POST /books/5? will it throw resource not found?

Comment: I feel the idempotency is the most distinguishing and important difference between PUT and POST

Comment: Hi ChanGan, here's an explanation which Wikipedia gives about your "POST /books/5" case: "Not generally used. Treat the addressed member as a collection in its own right and create a new entry in it."

Comment: this answer gives the impression that PUT and POST can be defined on the same resource, however the other difference next to idempotency is who controls the ID space. In PUT, the user is controlling the ID space by creating resources with a specific ID. In POST, the server is returning the ID that the user should reference in subsequent calls like GET. The above is weird because its's a mix of both.

Answer (score 123):

1. **GET**: Retrieves data from the server. Should have no other effect.
2. **PUT**: Replaces target resource with the request payload. Can be used to update or create a new resource.
3. **PATCH**: Similar to PUT, but used to update only certain fields within an existing resource.
4. **POST**: Performs resource-specific processing on the payload. Can be used for different actions including creating a new resource, uploading a file, or submitting a web form.
5. **DELETE**: Removes data from the server.
6. **TRACE**: Provides a way to test what the server receives. It simply returns what was sent.
7. **OPTIONS**: Allows a client to get information about the request methods supported by a service. The relevant response header is Allow with supported methods. Also used in CORS as preflight request to inform the server about actual the request method and ask about custom headers.
8. **HEAD**: Returns only the response headers.
9. **CONNECT**: Used by the browser when it knows it talks to a proxy and the final URI begins with `https://`. The intent of CONNECT is to allow end-to-end encrypted TLS sessions, so the data is unreadable to a proxy.

Comment: Is CONNECT fired prior to each request when using https?

Comment: Information given about PUT and POST is not right in this answer. PUT can be used to create a new entity as well as update an existing entity. POST is more generic and can be used to perform similar action like in PUT or can be used to perform any other action as well on the incoming entity (with side effects) and ideally, PUT should be idempotent where as POST may or may not be idempotent

Answer (score 72):

PUT is meant as a a method for "uploading" stuff to a particular URI, or overwriting what is already in that URI.

POST, on the other hand, is a way of submitting data RELATED to a given URI.

Refer to [the HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6)

Answer (score 48):

As far as i know, PUT is mostly used for update the records.

1. POST - To create document or any other resource
2. PUT  - To update the created document or any other resource.

But to be clear on that PUT usually 'Replaces' the existing record if it is there and creates if it not there..

Comment: What is a record in this context? The question is about HTTP Request.

Comment: What would POST do if the document/resource is already present? Will it throw an error, or will it just go off OK?

Comment: Here's not a place where you share "As far as I know" type opinions. We need brief, documental answers.

Answer (score 26):

**[Define operations in terms of HTTP methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#define-operations-in-terms-of-http-methods)**

The HTTP protocol defines a number of methods that assign semantic meaning to a request. The common HTTP methods used by most RESTful web APIs are:

**GET** retrieves a representation of the resource at the specified URI. The body of the response message contains the details of the requested resource.

**POST** creates a new resource at the specified URI. The body of the request message provides the details of the new resource. Note that POST can also be used to trigger operations that don't actually create resources.

**PUT** either creates or replaces the resource at the specified URI. The body of the request message specifies the resource to be created or updated.

**PATCH** performs a partial update of a resource. The request body specifies the set of changes to apply to the resource.

**DELETE** removes the resource at the specified URI.

The effect of a specific request should depend on whether the resource is a collection or an individual item. The following table summarizes the common conventions adopted by most RESTful implementations using the e-commerce example. Not all of these requests might be implemented—it depends on the specific scenario.

| Resource | POST | GET | PUT | DELETE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /customers | Create a new customer | Retrieve all customers | Bulk update of customers | Remove all customers |
| /customers/1 | Error | Retrieve the details for customer 1 | Update the details of customer 1 if it exists | Remove customer 1 |
| /customers/1/orders | Create a new order for customer 1 | Retrieve all orders for customer 1 | Bulk update of orders for customer 1 | Remove all orders for customer 1 |

**The differences between POST, PUT, and PATCH can be confusing.**

A **POST** request creates a resource. The server assigns a URI for the new resource and returns that URI to the client. In the `REST model`, you frequently apply `POST` requests to collections. The new resource is added to the collection. A `POST` request can also be used to submit data for processing to an existing resource, without any new resource being created.

A **PUT** request creates a resource or updates an existing resource. The client specifies the URI for the resource. The request body contains a complete representation of the resource. If a resource with this URI already exists, it is replaced. Otherwise, a new resource is created, if the server supports doing so. `PUT` requests are most frequently applied to resources that are individual items, such as a specific customer, rather than collections. A server might support updates but not creation via `PUT`. Whether to support creation via `PUT` depends on whether the client can meaningfully assign a URI to a resource before it exists. If not, then use `POST` to create resources and `PUT or PATCH` to update.

A **PATCH** request performs a partial update to an existing resource. The client specifies the URI for the resource. The request body specifies a set of changes to apply to the resource. This can be more efficient than using `PUT`, because the client only sends the changes, not the entire representation of the resource. Technically `PATCH` can also create a new resource (by specifying a set of updates to a "null" resource), if the server supports this.

`PUT` requests must be idempotent. If a client submits the same `PUT` request multiple times, the results should always be the same (the same resource will be modified with the same values). `POST and PATCH` requests are not guaranteed to be idempotent.

Comment: I think you have PUT and POST backwards

Comment: No. PUT is for actually placing literal content at a URL and it rarely has its place in a REST API. POST is more abstract and covers any sort of adding content that doesn't have the semantics of "Put this exact file at this exact URL".

Comment: −1 because in addition to **update**, PUT is also used to **create** a *target* resource (the resource identified by the request URI), contrary to POST which cannot create a target resource because it is not a CRUD operation on the resources’ states (data management) but a *process* operation (cf. RFC 7231). The process may create a resource but different from the target resource so that does make it a CRUD operation.

Comment: This is by far the best and most accurate explanation for Put and Post. It's the only one that talks about the client being able supply a meaningful URI to the resultant resource.

Comment: Is every request that does not change the server's state a GET request? For example an endpoint that identifies keywords from a text sent as the request's body - is such an endpoint GET endpoint?

Comment: @dpelisek There is no request body in GET method

Comment: @LongNguyen, what is it then? According your answer both post and get creates a resource. But this example does not creates any resource.

Comment: @dpelisek Could you please quote the sentences I mentioned that GET creates a resource?

Comment: sorry, I meant both post and put

Answer (score 23):

Others have already posted excellent answers, I just wanted to add that with most languages, frameworks, and use cases you'll be dealing with `POST` much, much more often than `PUT`.  To the point where `PUT, DELETE,` etc. are basically trivia questions.

Answer (score 21):

Please see: http://zacharyvoase.com/2009/07/03/http-post-put-diff/

I’ve been getting pretty annoyed lately by a popular misconception by web developers that a POST is used to create a resource, and a PUT is used to update/change one.

If you take a look at page 55 of RFC 2616 (“Hypertext Transfer Protocol – HTTP/1.1”), [Section 9.6](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) (“PUT”), you’ll see what PUT is actually for:

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI.

There’s also a handy paragraph to explain the difference between POST and PUT:

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed entity. That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway to some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts annotations. In contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request – the user agent knows what URI is intended and the server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource.

It doesn’t mention anything about the difference between updating/creating, because that’s not what it’s about. It’s about the difference between this:

```
obj.set_attribute(value) # A POST request.
```

And this:

```
obj.attribute = value # A PUT request.
```

So please, stop the spread of this popular misconception. Read your RFCs.

Comment: This seems pointlessly rude, and pedantic in a less-than-useful way. In the example of a PUT you cite, the new entity is, in a RESTful api, a 'new' record - and accessible at that location. It's questionable whether it's a good design choice to allow sub-members be mutable like that (I think it's not ideal), but even were it, you're using a subspecies to attack a lot of useful information. Most of the time, the description as it is usually stated is a great statement of both the RFC's content, summarized, and a statement of usual and customary practice. Also, it won't hurt you to be polite.

Comment: This cannot be upvoted enough. PUT has no place in a REST API. Most of the time, POST indicates the correct semantics.

Comment: Not said well, but indeed an accurate interpretation of the RFCs. The web developer world is quite a swamp of misinformation, it seems.

Comment: @Beefster There's no such thing as 'POST Indicates'. Najeebul made a great point here. How do you figure what it indicates? except that you just use it because you've always used it that way since the first day you learned it but don't really know why you should use it compared to the others?

Answer (score 14):

A POST is considered something of a factory type method.  You include data with it to create what you want and whatever is on the other end knows what to do with it.  A PUT is used to update existing data at a given URL, or to create something new when you know what the URI is going to be and it doesn't already exist (as opposed to a POST which will create something and return a URL to it if necessary).

Answer (score 14):

It should be pretty straightforward when to use one or the other, but complex wordings are a source of confusion for many of us.

### When to use them:

- Use `PUT` when you want to modify a singular resource that is already a part of resource collection. `PUT` replaces the resource in its entirety. Example: `PUT /resources/:resourceId`

  **Sidenote:** Use `PATCH` if you want to update a part of the resource.

---

- Use `POST` when you want to add a child resource under a collection of resources.
  Example: `POST => /resources`

---

### In general:

- Generally, in practice, always use **`PUT`** for *UPDATE* operations.
- Always use **`POST`** for *CREATE* operations.

---

### Example:

**`GET`**     /company/reports      **=>** *Get all reports*
**`GET`**     /company/reports/{id} **=>** *Get the report information identified by "id"*
**`POST`**    /company/reports      **=>** *Create a new report*
**`PUT`**     /company/reports/{id} **=>** *Update the report information identified by "id"*
**`PATCH`**     /company/reports/{id} **=>** *Update a part of the report information identified by "id"*
**`DELETE`**    /company/reports/{id} **=>** *Delete report by "id"*

Answer (score 6):

The difference between POST and PUT is that PUT is idempotent, that means, calling the same PUT request multiple times will always produce the same result(that is no side effect), while on the other hand, calling a POST request repeatedly may have (additional) side effects  of creating the same resource multiple times.

`GET` : Requests using GET only retrieve data , that is it requests a representation of the specified resource

`POST` : It sends data to the server to create a resource. The type of the body of the request is indicated by the Content-Type header. It often causes a change in state or side effects on the server

`PUT` : Creates a new resource or replaces a representation of the target resource with the request payload

`PATCH` : It is used to apply partial modifications to a resource

`DELETE` : It deletes the specified resource

`TRACE` : It performs a message loop-back test along the path to the target resource, providing a useful debugging mechanism

`OPTIONS` : It is used to describe the communication options for the target resource, the client can specify a URL for the OPTIONS method, or an asterisk (*) to refer to the entire server.

`HEAD` : It asks for a response identical to that of a GET request, but without the response body

`CONNECT` : It establishes a tunnel to the server identified by the target resource ,  can be used to access websites that use SSL (HTTPS)

Answer (score 5):

It would be worth mentioning that `POST` is subject to some common **Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks** while `PUT` isn't.

The CSRF below are **not possible with `PUT`** when the victim visits `attackersite.com`.

The **effect of the attack** is that the **victim unintentionally deletes a user** just because it (the victim) was logged-in as `admin` on `target.site.com`, before visiting `attackersite.com`:

**Malicious code on `attackersite.com`:**

**Case 1:** Normal request. saved `target.site.com` cookies will automatically be sent by the browser: (note: supporting `PUT` only, at the endpoint, is safer because it is not a supported `<form>` attribute value)

```
<!--deletes user with id 5-->
<form id="myform" method="post" action="http://target.site.com/deleteUser" >
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="5">
</form>
<script>document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('myform'));</script>
```

**Case 2:** XHR request. saved `target.site.com` cookies will automatically be sent by the browser: (note: supporting `PUT` only, at the endpoint, is safer because an attempt to send `PUT` would trigger a preflight request, whose response would prevent the browser from requesting the `deleteUser` page)

```
//deletes user with id 5
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://target.site.com/deleteUser");
xhr.withCredentials=true;
xhr.send(["userId=5"]);
```

> [MDN Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) : [..]Unlike “simple requests” (discussed above), --[[ Means: POST/GET/HEAD ]]--, for "preflighted" requests the browser first sends an HTTP request using the OPTIONS method[..]

> [cors in action](https://livebook.manning.com/book/cors-in-action/chapter-4/) :  [..]Certain types of requests, such as DELETE or PUT, need to go a step further and ask for the server’s permission before making the actual request[..]what is called a preflight request[..]

Answer (score 5):

In simple words you can say:

1.HTTP Get:It is used to get one or more items

2.HTTP Post:It is used to create an item

3.HTTP Put:It is used to update an item

4.HTTP Patch:It is used to partially update an item

5.HTTP Delete:It is used to delete an item

Answer (score 4):

**REST-ful usage**

`POST` is used to create a new resource and then returns the resource `URI`

```
EX 
      REQUEST : POST ..../books
        {
        "book":"booName",
        "author":"authorName"
        }
```

This call may create a new book and returns that book `URI`

```
Response ...THE-NEW-RESOURCE-URI/books/5
```

`PUT` is used to replace a resource, if that resource is exist then simply update it, but if that resource doesn't exist then create it,

```
REQUEST : PUT ..../books/5
{
"book":"booName",
"author":"authorName"
}
```

With `PUT` we know the resource identifier, but `POST` will return the new resource identifier

**Non REST-ful usage**

`POST` is used to initiate an action on the server side, this action may or may not create a resource, but this action will have side affects always it will change something on the server

`PUT` is used to place or replace literal content at a specific URL

**Another difference in both REST-ful and non REST-ful styles**

`POST` is Non-Idempotent Operation: It will cause some changes if executed multiple times with the same request.

`PUT` is Idempotent Operation: It will have no side-effects if executed multiple times with the same request.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there's no difference other than their title. There's actually a basic difference between GET and the others. With a "GET"-Request method, you send the data in the url-address-line, which are separated first by a question-mark, and then with a & sign.

But with a "POST"-request method, you can't pass data through the url, but you have to pass the data as an object in the so called "body" of the request. On the server side, you have then to read out the body of the received content in order to get the sent data.
But there's on the other side no possibility to send content in the body, when you send a "GET"-Request.

The claim, that "GET" is only for getting data and "POST" is for posting data, is absolutely wrong. Noone can prevent you from creating new content, deleting existing content, editing existing content or do whatever in the backend, based on the data, that is sent by the "GET" request or by the "POST" request. And nobody can prevent you to code the backend in a way, that with a "POST"-Request, the client asks for some data.

With a request, no matter which method you use, you call a URL and send or don't send some data to specify, which information you want to pass to the server to deal with your request, and then the client gets an answer from the server. The data can contain whatever you want to send, the backend is allowed to do whatever it wants with the data and the response can contain any information, that you want to put in there.

There are only these two BASIC METHODS. GET and POST. But it's their structure, which makes them different and not what you code in the backend. In the backend you can code whatever you want to, with the received data. But with the "POST"-request you have to send/retrieve the data in the body and not in the url-addressline, and with a "GET" request, you have to send/retrieve data in the url-addressline and not in the body. That's all.

All the other methods, like "PUT", "DELETE" and so on, they have the same structure as "POST".

The POST Method is mainly used, if you want to hide the content somewhat, because whatever you write in the url-addressline, this will be saved in the cache and a GET-Method is the same as writing a url-addressline with data. So if you want to send sensitive data, which is not always necessarily username and password, but for example some ids or hashes, which you don't want to be shown in the url-address-line, then you should use the POST method.

Also the URL-Addressline's length is limited to 1024 symbols, whereas the "POST"-Method is not restricted. So if you have a bigger amount of data, you might not be able to send it with a GET-Request, but you'll need to use the POST-Request. So this is also another plus point for the POST-request.

But dealing with the GET-request is way easier, when you don't have complicated text to send.
Otherwise, and this is another plus point for the POST method, is, that with the GET-method you need to url-encode the text, in order to be able to send some symbols within the text or even spaces. But with a POST method you have no restrictions and your content doesn't need to be changed or manipulated in any way.

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

- Use `PUT` to create or replace the state of the *target* resource with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request. That *standardized* intended effect is *idempotent* so it informs intermediaries that they can repeat a request in case of communication failure.
- Use `POST` otherwise (including to create or replace the state of a resource other than the target resource). Its intended effect is *not standardized* so intermediaries cannot rely on any universal property.

### References

The latest authoritative description of the semantic difference between the `POST` and `PUT` request methods is given in [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231) (Roy Fielding, Julian Reschke, 2014):

> The fundamental difference between the `POST` and `PUT` methods is highlighted by the different intent for the enclosed representation. The target resource in a `POST` request is intended to handle the enclosed representation according to the resource's own semantics, whereas the enclosed representation in a `PUT` request is defined as replacing the state of the target resource. Hence, the intent of `PUT` is idempotent and visible to intermediaries, even though the exact effect is only known by the origin server.

In other words, the intended effect of `PUT` is *standardized* (create or replace the state of the *target* resource with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request) and so is common to all target resources, while the intended effect of `POST` is *not standardized* and so is specific to each target resource. Thus `POST` can be used for anything, including for achieving the intended effects of `PUT` and other request methods (`GET`, `HEAD`, `DELETE`, `CONNECT`, `OPTIONS`, and `TRACE`).

But it is recommended to always use the more specialized request method rather than `POST` when applicable because it provides more information to intermediaries for automating information retrieval (since `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, and `TRACE` are defined as *safe*), handling communication failure (since `GET`, `HEAD`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `OPTIONS`, and `TRACE` are defined as *idempotent*), and optimizing cache performance (since `GET` and `HEAD` are defined as *cacheable*), as explained in [*It Is Okay to Use POST*](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post) (Roy Fielding, 2009):

> `POST` only becomes an issue when it is used in a situation for which some other method is ideally suited: e.g., retrieval of information that should be a representation of some resource (`GET`), complete replacement of a representation (`PUT`), or any of the other standardized methods that tell intermediaries something more valuable than “this may change something.” The other methods are more valuable to intermediaries because they say something about how failures can be automatically handled and how intermediate caches can optimize their behavior. `POST` does not have those characteristics, but that doesn’t mean we can live without it. `POST` serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.”

Answer (score 0):

Both PUT and POST are Rest Methods .

PUT - If we make the same request twice using PUT using same parameters both times, the second request will not have any effect. This is why PUT is generally used for the Update scenario,calling Update more than once with the same parameters doesn't do anything more than the initial call hence PUT is idempotent.

POST is not idempotent  , for instance Create will create two separate entries into the target hence it is not idempotent so CREATE is used widely in POST.

Making the same call using POST with same parameters each time will cause two different things to happen, hence why POST is commonly used for the Create scenario

Answer (score 0):

Post and Put are mainly used for post the data and other update the data. But you can do the same with post request only.