# Why does a PUT request require x-www-form-urlencoded and not work with form-data?

Tags: php, api, http, rest, http-headers

I'm trying to retrieve the data from a PUT request.

Currently I have it working with the below code:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $parsedArray);
```

But this seems to only be supported with x-www-url-encoded and not the standard form-data, is there a work around that I've missed?

If it's any addition I have the following headers set on all requests to my API:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

If more info is needed i can provide it, not too sure what else could be effecting this?

Cheers in advance,
Jamie

Answer (score 2):

I found this, it provides good extra background (got curious myself):
[PUT vs POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request)

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to PUT - POST suffers the same problem.

When PHP parses a `multipart/form-data` request, `php://input` is no longer available.

This has caused many problems for me in the past!

Unfortunately the only workaround is to have the file's contents be submitted as part of the form-data, possibly base64-encoded (so it doesn't have to urlencode all the binary data). It's a hassle, but sadly that's the only way to handle this particular situation...

Comment: I see. I think I may be using `php://input` wrong then. I'm not looking to pass a file, just get form-data into my PHP script for a PUT. Does it make any difference that I'm not dealing with files, and instead just parameters/fields?

Comment: @JamieStreet If you're not dealing with files, you generally shouldn't be using `multipart/form-data` over `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (yes, I know it's been a while, but still there simply hadn't been an answer so far)

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue about it on PHP.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55815

On the other hand, as they say over there, PUT is not the proper way to upload a file. 
It is a discussion about to solve the problem in Symfony Framework or not.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10381#issuecomment-36726684