# PHP/Apache - PUT/DELETE data is lost after 5 requests

Tags: php, apache

I'm simply trying to do PUT/DELETE requests in my PHP application, but after the first 5 requests, the data is lost.

I've reduced the code to this to illustrate the issue:

**index.php**

```
$h = fopen('php://input', 'r');
var_dump(fread($h, 1024));
die();
```

**CLI input**

```
curl -X PUT http://cms.dev.com -d '{"foo":"bar"}'
```

So, for the first 5 times I run that, I get:

```
string(13) "{"foo":"bar"}"
```

Then, from the 6th onwards, I get:

```
string(0) ""
```

I'm running PHP Version 5.6.0beta1 and Apache/2.2.26, installed on OSX 10.9.3 via Mac Ports.

POST works fine.

**EDIT** It might be worth noting this can be replicated on 2 other colleague's MacPorts setups, but can't on MAMP, which seems to act correctly.

Does anyone have ideas? It's driving me crazy!

Thanks,
Todd

Comment: Why do you want to use PUT rather than POST? I understood that PUT was designed for adding / updating a resource with a specified identifier, but you don't seem to be using one in your example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request.

Comment: It's for a backbone.js application, I'm updating a user. The code above is just to replicate the issue.

Comment: So, are you providing an identifier with your PUT request in the "real" code? I know this is sounding less and less relevant (given your edit about it working on MAMP but not via MacPorts), but it may still be a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to php 5.6beta3 fixed the issue.

Must have been a bug in php 5.6beta1!

Hopefully this'll help someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this using the built-in webserver, which might indicate an interaction between apache and php.

Try running :-

```
php -S localhost:8001
```

in one terminal and

```
for n in `seq 1 100`; do curl -X PUT http://localhost:8001 -d '{"foo":"bar"}'; done
```

in another - see if it's limited to php or at the mod_php level.

My testing is on a linux box with 5.4.9 fwiw.

Comment: Cheers for the help.

This always returns as an empty string, doesn't even give me the 5.

Comment: Curl activities can be quite slow, even on localhost.  and usually a write/put operation is not buffered.  Are you waiting for the prior cURL operation to complete before starting the next?  BTW: the line: php -S localhost:8001 results in an immediate error message on my linux box, and the man page shows no '-S' option.  maybe it should be '-s' which echos any HTML syntax highlited source.  However, that also fails, saying it cannot open localhost:8001