# Passing data in non-POST call

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

For a REST api, I know it is acceptable to pass data in a `POST` call:

```
if method == 'POST':
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
```

Is it acceptable to pass data in a `PUT` or `DELETE` call? Or are you not supposed to send any data parms, and only request the specified url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) explains everything you need to know.

`PUT` is [very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request) to `POST` in a REST API.

**POST**

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics. <sup>[RFC 7231 #4.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)</sup>

**PUT**

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload. <sup>[RFC 7231 #4.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)</sup>

Both request data. Furthermore, the RFC explicitly highlights the difference, since it is indeed slight:

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT methods is highlighted by the different intent for the enclosed representation. The target resource in a POST request is intended to handle the enclosed representation according to the resource's own semantics, whereas the enclosed representation in a PUT request is defined as replacing the state of the target resource.  Hence, the intent of PUT is idempotent and visible to intermediaries, even though the exact effect is only known by the origin server.

Regarding `DELETE`, the RFC says the following:

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

I presume that means that you shouldn't send data. Regardless, the RFC does mention

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method

which is spot on, in my opinion. You should just avoid `DELETE` altogether.