# Dropbox direct upload files from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I am trying to upload files directly to dropbox [from a browser / web application], The "uploadFile" function on the code API needs the file to be uploaded available on the server, this puts me in trouble, because I do not want any files to be uploaded to my server and from there to dropbox.

```
$f = fopen("test.jpg", "rb"); // requires file on server
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("test.jpg", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
fclose($f);
```

Tried out this https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js disappointed to say that there is no clear documentation, many of the links on the documentation part is broken.

I need the files to be uploaded to my account and the clients need not login to dropbox.

Any pointers would be really appreciated. looking for Ajax / JavaScript methods.

**Update**

I have tried the following, but no response from Dropbox

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="doUpload(event)">
```

JavaScript

```
var doUpload = function(event){

var input = event.target;
var reader = new FileReader();


  reader.onload = function(){
    var arrayBuffer = reader.result;

   $.ajax({  
    url: "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/uploads/" + input.files[0].name,  
    headers: {  
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + MyAccessToken,  
        contentLength: file.size  
    },  
    crossDomain: true,  
    crossOrigin: true,  
    type: 'PUT',  
    contentType: input.files[0].type,  
    data: arrayBuffer,  
    dataType: 'json',  
    processData: false,
    success : function(result) {
        $('#uploadResults').html(result);
    }
    });
  }
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: I faced a problem with the Dropbox API docs not too long ago. The user @smarx works for Dropbox and was keen to hear user's views on the docs.

Comment: This code looks reasonable. When you say "no response from Dropbox," do you truly mean there's no response to the HTTP request? (You can look in the network tab in your browser to see.) It seems more likely that the API is returning an error.

Comment: Two possible issues that jump out: `contentLength` is a bogus header name (though I doubt that would break anything), and `file.size` probably doesn't work unless the variable `file` is defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @smarx with his pointers I was able to reach the final solution.

Also I have added a few extra features like listening to upload progress so that the users can be showed with the upload progress percentage.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="doUpload(event)">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var doUpload = function(event){

      var input = event.target;
      var reader = new FileReader();


      reader.onload = function(){
        var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
        var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( arrayBuffer );
        var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: input.files[0].type } );
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );   

        $.ajax({  
          url: "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/YourDirectory/" + input.files[0].name,  
          headers: {  
            'Authorization':'Bearer ' +YourToken,  
            'Content-Length':input.files[0].size  
          },  
          crossDomain: true,  
          crossOrigin: true,  
          type: 'PUT',  
          contentType: input.files[0].type,  
          data: arrayBuffer,  
          dataType: 'json',  
          processData: false,
          xhr: function()
          {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
           //Upload progress, litsens to the upload progress 
           //and get the upload status
           xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
              var percentComplete = parseInt( parseFloat(evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
              //Do something with upload progress
              $('#uploadProgress').html(percentComplete);
              $('#uploadProgressBar').css('width',percentComplete+'%');
             }
            }, false);
           },
         beforeSend: function(){
           // Things you do before sending the file 
           // like showing the loader GIF
         },
         success : function(result) {
           // Display the results from dropbox after upload 
           // Other stuff on complete
          },

        }); 
       }
     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
    }
```

U have used the PUT method as our only objective is to upload files,As per my studies on various resources ( [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request) and [zacharyvoase](http://zacharyvoase.com/2009/07/03/http-post-put-diff/) ) A put method can stream large files, also its desigend to put files on a specified URI , if file exist the file must be replaced. A PUT method cannot be moved to a different URL other than the URL Specified.

**The Risk**

You are at risk by using access token at client side, there needs to be high security measures to mask the token. But modern Web dev tools like Browser consoles , Firebug etc can monitor your server requests and can see your access token.

Answer (score 8):

Dropbox just posted a blog with instructions on how to do this. You can find it at https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/03/how-formio-uses-dropbox-as-a-file-backend-for-javascript-apps/ (Full disclosure, I wrote the blog post.)

Here is how to upload a file.

```
/**
 * Two variables should already be set.
 * dropboxToken = OAuth token received then signing in with OAuth.
 * file = file object selected in the file widget.
 */

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt) {
    var percentComplete = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    // Upload in progress. Do something here with the percent complete.
};

xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var fileInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        // Upload succeeded. Do something here with the file info.
    }
    else {
        var errorMessage = xhr.response || 'Unable to upload file';
        // Upload failed. Do something here with the error.
    }
};

xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + dropboxToken);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({
    path: '/' +  file.name,
    mode: 'add',
    autorename: true,
    mute: false
}));

xhr.send(file);
```

Then to download a file from dropbox do this.

```
var downloadFile = function(evt, file) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: ’application/octet-stream’});
      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, file.name, true);
    }
    else {
      var errorMessage = xhr.response || 'Unable to download file';
      // Upload failed. Do something here with the error.
    }
  };

  xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + dropboxToken);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({
    path: file.path_lower
  }));
  xhr.send();
}
```

FileSaver and Blob will not work on older browsers so you could add a workaround to them.

As other answers have noted, each session uploading or downloading the file will need to have access to a dropbox token. Sending someone else's token to a user is a security issue since having the token will give them complete control over the dropbox account. The only way to make this work is to have each person authenticate with Dropbox and get their own token.

At [Form.io](https://form.io) we've implemented both the authentication and the upload/download into our platform. This makes it really easy to build web apps with dropbox as a backend for files.

Answer (score 1):

"I need the files to be uploaded to my account and the clients need not login to dropbox."

Then you'll really need to do the upload server-side. To do it client side would mean sending the access token to the browser, at which point any user of your app could use that access token to do whatever they wanted with your account. (E.g. delete all the other files, upload their private DVD collection, etc.)

For security reasons, I would strongly recommend doing the upload server-side where you can keep the access token a secret.

Comment: while its true to keep the access token a secret, its also not advisable to upload bigger files to the server[ > 100 mb] at first and from there to dropbox. Any method to directly upload files my dropbox account would be great.

Comment: Having researched that this evening, it looks as though S3 provide item by item signatures for uploads, which is much more secure than what handing out your token

Answer (score 1):

The answers given so far don't utilize the Dropbox javascript SDK which I think would prob be the best way to go about it. Check out this link here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/javascript/upload/index.html

which provides an example which is ofc dependent on having downloaded the SDK. (Edit: after playing with SDK I realize that it creates a POST request similar to the accepted answer in this thread.  However something the popular answer omits is the presence of an OPTIONS preflight call that the sdk makes prior to the actual POST)

I might also add that something that is not shown in the dropbox sdk examples is that you can upload a blob object to dropbox; this is useful for instance if you want to dynamically extract images from a canvas and upload them and don't want to upload something that has been selected from the file system via the file uploaded input.

Here is a brief example of the scenario I'm describing:

```
//code below after having included dropbox-sdk-js in your project.  
//Dropbox is in scope!
var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
//numerous stack overflow examples on creating a blob from data uri
var blob = dataURIToBlob(canvas.toDataUrl());
//the path here is the path of the file as it will exist on dropbox.
//should be unique or you will get a 4xx error
dbx.filesUpload({path: `unq_filename.png`, contents: blob})
```

Comment: You have missed /(slash) here:

dbx.filesUpload({path: '/filename.png', contents: file})

Answer (score -1):

### upload.html

Upload

### upload.js

```
$('#form_wizard_1 .button-submit').click(function () {
      var ACCESS_TOKEN ="Your token get from dropbox";
      var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('files1');
      var file = fileInput.files[0];
      res=dbx.filesUpload({path: '/' + file.name, contents: file})
      .then(function(response) {
      var results = document.getElementById('results');
      results.appendChild(document.createTextNode('File uploaded!'));
      res=response;
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
       console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: This would be a good answer but you need to include the fact that the Dropbox object is from the SDK.  Also this is basically just a cut and paste of a documentation example.