# Dropbox API PHP upload file issue

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I use a PHP server to manage Dropbox files for customers.

My server records the user's access token.

But When customers want to upload a file to theirs Dropbox,they must first upload file to my server,and my server use http(php curl) send file to Dropbox through Dropbox Api.

This raises some problem：

1:If C + + client use Dropbox API, they can upload files directly from the local,but use PHP server the file just can local->server->Dropbox,This results in a lower user experience and give the server tremendous pressure.

Is there any way for customers to upload files directly to Dropbox instead of PHP server get whole file and forward.

Comment: Nice question, i'd like to see is there any way, but how do i think, there's no way to do it directly to dropbox before you get it to the server, which one can then upload to dropbox with api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropbox direct upload files from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399049/dropbox-direct-upload-files-from-browser)

Comment: After a long time I think,if i want to do it directly to dropbox, i must use The client language, such as javascript. but My PHP server just provide to client API.