# Difference between Put and Post in Rest

Tags: web-services, rest, wcf-rest

Can anyone please explain what is the difference between PUT and POST request.Also I want to know about PATCH request.

Comment: This has already been asked and answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/630453/7012517 refer to this if u are confused what to use..

Answer (score -2):

- POST should be used to create a resource
- PUT should be used to update a resource
- PATCH request should be used when you want to update just a part of the resource.

**EXAMPLE:**

- Creating a new user
- POST Update the user (first name, last name,
  address, city, etc.)
- PUT PATCH - change the user's password