# Ensure Multiple Select Element Has Non Empty Option Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown where the default selected option has a value of `empty`. After clicking the submit button the `save()` function is called where if any of the selects have 'empty' chosen its suppose to display an alert and break. It displays the alert but if I choose an option for each select it never submits the post. What am I doing wrong?

```
function save() {

    let order = [];

    $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]').each(function(){
        let id = this[this.selectedIndex].id;
        let value = this.value;

        // if any of the selects values === 'empty' break 
        if (value === 'empty') {
            console.log("empty");
            $(".alertEmptySelect").show();
            return;

            // else continue if all selects have a value 
            order.push({id: id, status: value});
            let data = JSON.stringify(order);

            $.ajax({
                method: 'put',
                url: '',
                data:  data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function(response){
                    $(".alertSubmitted").show("slow");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    let errorString = '';
                    $.each(data.responseJSON, function (key, value) {
                        errorString += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
                    });
                    $('.alertError').show().html(errorString);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I have a table which is created by a loop. Each row has its own select which is why I have it declared as an array

```
<select name="statusSelect[]" id="statusSelect" onchange="changeColor(this, {{$product->id}})" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
    <option id={{$product->id}} value="a">A</option>
    <option id={{$product->id}} value="r">R</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It looks like you put the AJAX request within the if statement that returns if a value is "empty". You need to close out of that control statement or the following code(the code that actually utilizes the AJAX request) will never run.

Comment: Your AJAX call is within the `if (value === 'empty') { ... }` `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You need to change from PUT to POST have a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request)

Second, you needn't go to the server with every valid select but what you should do is collect your data and then if all valid go do ajax request so your function should look like this:

```
    function save() {

  let order = [];
  //as you have many selects you need this flag to cancel ajax 
    request if any select is empyt
  let isEmpty = false;
  $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]').each(function() {
    let id = this[this.selectedIndex].id;
    let value = this.value;
    debugger;
    // if any of the selects values === 'empty' break the each
    //and set the flag to beak the ajax request
    if (value === 'empty') {
      console.log("empty");
      $(".alertEmptySelect").show();
      isEmpty = true;
      return;
    }
    // order array must be in the each loop to carry all the data
    order.push({
      id: id,
      status: value
    });

  });
  if (isEmpty) {
    console.log("save canceled");
    return;
  }
  let data = JSON.stringify(order);
  console.log(data);
  //should be outside the each to go only one time to the sever (make sure to put the Url)
  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'your Url',
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log('success.');
      $(".alertSubmitted").show("slow");
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(data);
      let errorString = '';
      $.each(data.responseJSON, function(key, value) {
        errorString += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
      });
      $('.alertError').show().html(errorString);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Waiting for your feed back

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are simply forgetting to close your empty value condition:

```
function save() {
  let order = [];

  $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]').each(function() {
    let id = this[this.selectedIndex].id;
    let value = this.value;

    // if any of the selects values === 'empty' break 
    if (value === 'empty') {
      console.log("empty");
      $(".alertEmptySelect").show();
      return;
    }

    // else continue if all selects have a value 
    order.push({id: id, status: value});
    let data = JSON.stringify(order);

    $.ajax({
      method: 'put',
      url: '',
      data:  data,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(response){
        $(".alertSubmitted").show("slow");
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        let errorString = '';
        $.each(data.responseJSON, function (key, value) {
            errorString += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
        });
        $('.alertError').show().html(errorString);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem as before. I don't want the form to be submitted if any of the selects values are empty. If one select has chosen a value this code will submit the form. I want it to completely stop and not submit anything.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is break the loop that is checking each of the select values. If it comes up empty just display the alert and exit out of the entire function. Dont try to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @twmulloy, curly braces issue.

Validate no **empty** selection on all dropdowns:

```
  // all dropdowns
  var allDropdowns = $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]');

  // empty selected options
  var emptySelectedOptions = allDropdowns.find('[value=empty]:selected');

  // flag if valid
  var isValid = (emptySelectedOptions.length === 0);

    if (!isValid){
    // exit
    alert('Please select option from all!');
    return;
  }
```

Reuse list of all dropdowns to iterate through each dropdowns:
`allDropdowns.each`

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AmitKB/9of6pxnt/2/) and overall code for **save** function:

```
function save() {

  let order = [];

    // all dropdowns
  var allDropdowns = $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]'),

    // empty selected options
    emptySelectedOptions = allDropdowns.find('[value=empty]:selected'),

    // flag if valid
    isValid = (emptySelectedOptions.length === 0);

 if (!isValid){
    // exit
    alert('Please select option from all!');
    return;
  }

  allDropdowns.each(function() {
    let id = this[this.selectedIndex].id;
    let value = this.value;

    alert('Saving...');

    // else continue if all selects have a value 
    order.push({
      id: id,
      status: value
    });
    let data = JSON.stringify(order);

    $.ajax({
      method: 'put',
      url: '',
      data: data,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(response) {
        $(".alertSubmitted").show("slow");
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let errorString = '';
        $.each(data.responseJSON, function(key, value) {
          errorString += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
        });
        $('.alertError').show().html(errorString);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if 1 select has chosen a value, and 3 havent, it will submit the form because 1 has. If any of the selects values are empty I want it to quit looping and display the alert and not submit the form.