# Ensure Multiple Select Elements Has Option Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which is created by a loop with an X amount of rows. Each row has a select. I want to loop through each select and if any doesnt have a value selected, completely stop the function and do not submit the form. The problem now is that if one row has a selected value, and 2 do not, it will submit that one row but I need it to not submit unless all rows have a selected value.

Here is a jsfiddle with an example of the problem

https://jsfiddle.net/ypx91hk0/2/

Code

```js
function save() {

  let order = [];

  $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]').each(function() {
    let id = this[this.selectedIndex].id;
    let value = this.value;

    if (value === 'empty') {
      console.log("empty");
      $(".alertEmptySelect").show();
      return;
    }

    order.push({id: id, status: value});
    let data = JSON.stringify(order);

    $.ajax({
      method: 'put',
      url: '',
      data:  data,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(response){
        $(".alertSubmitted").show("slow");
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        let errorString = '';
        $.each(data.responseJSON, function (key, value) {
            errorString += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
        });
        $('.alertError').show().html(errorString);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
 

<select name="statusSelect[]" id="statusSelect" onchange="changeColor(this, {{$product->id}})" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
    <option id={{$product->id}} value="a">A</option>
    <option id={{$product->id}} value="r">R</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The `id` of an element in an `HTML` `document` should be unique. Where is `changeColor` defined at linked jsfiddle?

Comment: What about using try-catch block? Right now the `break` statement is only breaking out of the function passed into `$.each()`; as a result you will still loop through all select boxes. You can put your call to `save()` inside a `try` block, and throw an error -- this way the error will bubble up through function call stack and you can catch it and handle.

Comment: [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200759/)

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If yes, can you please upvote and mark the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check before your each loop.

```
var hasEmptySelect = $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]')
   .map((idx, elem) => elem.value)
   .filter(value => value === "empty")
   .length > 0;
```

So you end with :

```
function save() {

    let order = [];

    var hasEmptySelect = $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]')
       .map((idx, elem) => elem.value)
       .filter(value => value === "empty")
       .length > 0;

    if (hasEmptySelect) {
        return;
    }

    // The rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a separate function for your ajax call, and call that function only when your `order.length === $('select').length` which means all selects have been selected.

```
function save() {

  let order = [];

  $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]').each(function() {
    let id = this[this.selectedIndex].id;
    let value = this.value;

    // if any of the selects values === 'empty' break 
    if (value === 'empty') {
      console.log("empty");
      alert('empty');
      $(".alertEmptySelect").show();
      return;
    }

    alert('Saving...');

    // else continue if all selects have a value 
    order.push({
      id: id,
      status: value
    });
    if(order.length === $('select').length)
       saveValues(JSON.stringify(order));
  });

  function saveValues(data){
  $.ajax({
      method: 'put',
      url: '',
      data: data,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(response) {
        $(".alertSubmitted").show("slow");
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let errorString = '';
        $.each(data.responseJSON, function(key, value) {
          errorString += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
        });
        $('.alertError').show().html(errorString);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explaining first: I would suggest to keep a variable, say, var flag = 0 outside your loop. Then increment this flag value by 1 on each iteration of the loop only if the loop meets your condition, i.e; an option was selected for that row's select element.

After the loop completes all iteration, check that the value of flag variable is equal to the number of iterations of the loop. That is, if there are total 5 select elements, when the loop finishes the value of flag will be 5 if each select element had an option/value selected by the user. And then only you submit the form/call the ajax function. Below is the code that works. I am using jquery. :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <select name="statusSelect[]" id="statusSelect" onchange="changeColor(this, 123)" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
      <option id="123" value="a">A</option>
      <option id="456" value="r">R</option>
    </select>
    <select name="statusSelect[]" id="statusSelect"  class="form-control" required>
      <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
      <option id="123" value="a">A</option>
      <option id="456" value="r">R</option>
    </select>
    <select name="statusSelect[]" id="statusSelect" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
      <option id="123" value="a">A</option>
      <option id="456" value="r">R</option>
    </select>
    <select name="statusSelect[]" id="statusSelect"  class="form-control" required>
      <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
      <option id="123" value="a">A</option>
      <option id="456" value="r">R</option>
    </select>
    <button>
    Save
    </button>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
      let flag = 0, rows = 0;
      let order = [];

      $('select[name="statusSelect[]"]').each(function() {
        rows = rows + 1;
        let id = this[this.selectedIndex].id;
        let value = this.value;

        // if any of the selects values === 'empty' break 
        if (value === 'empty') {
          console.log("empty");
          alert('empty');
          $(".alertEmptySelect").show();
          return;
        }

        else //since a value was selected, increase flat by 1 and add order to array that will be used in ajax function as data
        {
          flag =  flag + 1;
          order.push({
            id: id,
            status: value
          });
        }
      });    //end of loop


      //now check if flag variable = total number of iterations/rows
        if(flag == rows)
        {   //call ajax and etc. etc.
         let data = JSON.stringify(order);  
          $.ajax({
            method: 'put',
            url: '',
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
              $(".alertSubmitted").show("slow");
            },
            error: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              let errorString = '';
              $.each(data.responseJSON, function(key, value) {
                errorString += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
              });
              $('.alertError').show().html(errorString);
            }
          });
        } 

        // else if flag != row, show alert to user
        else alert('select all options');

      });
     }); 
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```