# Python Requests - Uploading a Zip file

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm having a zip file that needs to be uploaded. When I use the CURL command, it is  uploading it but when I try the same using Python Requests, i get `HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed`.
The zip file is usually around 500kb.

Curl command -

`curl -u<username>:<password> -T /log/system/check/index.zip "<target URL>"`

Python Script (tried 2 different ways) -

1:

```
import requests
files = {'file': open('/log/system/check/index.zip', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, auth=('<username>', '<password>'))
```

2:

```
import requests
fileobj = open('/log/system/check/index.zip', 'rb')
r = requests.post(url, auth=('<username>', '<password>'), files={"archive": ("index.zip", fileobj)})
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: So the `curl` command succeeds? The `curl` manpage says this of `-T`: `If this is used on an HTTP(S) server, the PUT command will be used.` So, curl is using `PUT`, not `POST`. Does your endpoint allow `POST`?

Comment: i tried using PUT now and see the error - `Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable'`, not sure if any proxy is required

Comment: But just to be clear, the `curl` command you listed works fine?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly fine. it's uploading the files.

Answer (score 6):

may be this will help you.

```
 with open(zipname, 'rb') as f:
uploadbase = requests.put('url',
                    auth=(base, pwd),
                    data=f,
                    headers={'X-File-Name' : zipname, 
                                  'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="{0}"; filename="{0}"'.format(zipname), 
                                   'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'})
```

[the difference between put and post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request)

Comment: Thanks save my day

Answer (score 1):

`curl -T ...` uses PUT method instead of POST.
As the error message says, you should use

`r = requests.put(url, ...)`

Comment: i tried using PUT now and see the error - `Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable'`, not sure if any proxy is required, am i missing anything?