# How to call dynamic Request Method in retrofit android

Tags: android, api, request, retrofit, retrofit2

I have two methods to call an API.

1.POST

2.PUT

Currently, i keep the two versions like

```
@POST("api_end_point")
  Call<ProfessionalResponse> ProfessionalData(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
            @Body ProfessionalInsertData body);

@PUT("api_end_point")
  Call<ProfessionalResponse> ProfessionalData(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
            @Body ProfessionalInsertData body);
```

How can I reduce this to a single function or single call in java or kotlin

Comment: I don't think it can be done.

Comment: no it can not be done please check it -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. You can check this [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2839) from github. As comment said it is better to use for this service OkHttp directly which allows you to control all aspects of the HTTP request dynamically.