# Get Request Vulnerabilities Over Post

Tags: rest

I Have an API which fetches data for a particular user based on the supplied User ID. Since I am only fetching the data from a DB, I have made this API use `GET` Requests.

```
URL : https://ui.sms.co.in:8443/config/v1/camp
HTTP Method: GET
Request Parameters:
type:1
userId:1000
startDate:2019-05-28
endDate:2019-05-28
```

After Reading from various Websites, I found that I should not expose `UserId` in the `URL` and I should change the API from using `GET` to `POST`. By making it `POST`, I will not be exposing any data in the `URL`, but I don't want to make it `POST` since I am not creating any resource. Should I make it `POST`; would that be wise?

Comment: rule of thumb is to not put sensitive data in GET parameters.  are user id numbers sensitive information? make it a POST instead. by the way, user ids are usually not sensitive, for example your StackOverflow user ID is 8523074. my own is 1067003.

Comment: Are you not [confusing `POST` with `PUT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request)? It's perfectly fine (and recommended) to [`POST` (potentially) sensitive data such as user IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them) and login credentials.

Comment: @hanshenrik it's a business requirement. i cannot expose userId

Comment: @AshishUpadhyay then make it a POST request, do not put it in the URL.

Comment: You cannot expose the userid specifically, or you cannot expose any unique identifying property of a user at all? If the former, use `GET` with an arbitrary unique identifier, such as a UUID.