# When use POST and PUT Method In Laravel?

Tags: laravel, post, put

I don't know exact difference between POST and PUT method.Some of the people said on internet that when you update record at time you have to use PUT method instead of POST, i don't know is it true??

form Internet if your website URL in POST method
1. www.example.com/user/{id}/update  :- PUT use
2. www.example.com/user/update       :- POST use 
this is right or not ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a POST and a PUT HTTP REQUEST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request)

Comment: I am asking which method should i use in laravel when i update record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're inserting a new data you'll most likely use `POST` method

```
Route::post('new/data', 'NewDataController@store');
```

If you want to edit or add a new data that is not existing, you must use `PUT` method

```
Route::put('/data', 'NewDataController@update');
```