# What is the correct method in REST API for adding an item to a collection - POST or PUT

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

There are `users` in the application which have preferences - favourite authors. A user can change this list. Authors are in the `authors` collection of a `User` entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id

     ....
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> authors=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

A user can edit his profile and change this list by adding or removing an author. 
On the one hand, adding or removing authors means just editing a profile, that's why currently I'm using a `PUT` method:

```
@PutMapping("/api/profile/author/add")
@PutMapping("/api/profile/author/remove")
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct. Another variant is to use `POST` and `DELETE` methods as the user adds and removes items:

```
@PostMapping("/api/profile/author/add")
@DeleteMapping("/api/profile/author/remove")
```

So what is correct variant and what's the reason?

Answer (score 6):

If you check [RFC 7231 Section 4.3.4 PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), you'll see that

> **4.3.4. PUT**
>
> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.

In simple terms, PUT is when you either create a resource at url, or replace it completely (a file upload is an easy example).
In your case, an author is not entity in itself (I can see that its just a `String` and the list is an `@ElementCollection`). Which means, when you add an author, you're *modifying* the `User` entity. i.e, you're ***not***
*creating or replacing* the 'User'. Therefore, PUT is not appropriate for adding the author.
PUT is also *not* for deleting an entity. You should consider DELETE for that.

Now, [RFC 7231 Section 4.3.4 POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) says this:

> **4.3.3.  POST**

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the
> representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's
> own specific semantics.  For example, POST is used for the following
> functions (among others):
>
> - Providing a block of data, such as the fields entered into an HTML
>   form, to a data-handling process;
> - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list,
>   blog, or similar group of articles;
> - Creating a new resource that has yet to be identified by the
>   origin server; and
> - Appending data to a resource's existing representation(s)

Again, in simple words, POST can be a request to [initiate an action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107415/1630255) at the server. The last two in the example list above applies to your case - you're appending or creating an author. Which means POST is appropriate for adding the author.

Conclusion:
Use POST and DELETE for adding and deleting authors.

On a side note, you should probably get rid of the `add` and `remove` at the end of the url. Let the HTTP Methods POST and DELETE differentiate the actions.
So it should be

```
@PostMapping("/api/profile/author")
@DeleteMapping("/api/profile/author")
```

Comment: PUT `replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.` If look not at authors, but at a User entity, we replace one representation of a user with another (which contains another list of authors). So it seems that the answer depends on what entity we are talking about.

Comment: If you replace the `User` entity entirely and not update a part of it, then yes its a PUT.

Comment: May be I should use PATCH /api/profile and provide a new list of authors?

Comment: @Ekaterina yes, that would work too..but I'd say - don't fret over it too much..Use the HTTP standards as a guideline for implementing your API - this will help others who work with it- and just implement it. If you're stuck second guessing , you're slowing down for no reason at all. Happy coding :) !!

Answer (score 1):

PUT is a request method with remote authoring semantics; you would normally expect that the target resource will be the thing that you are editing.

In other words, the @PutMapping would normally be using the same URI (or URI template) as the @GetMapping.

```
GET /profile

// Make local edits to the document

PUT /profile
```

If the list of favorite authors is a separate resource, that's also fine.  The pattern would be the same:

```
GET /profile/authors

// Make local edits

PUT /profile/authors
```

The point being that I can use *any* HTTP aware editor to make changes to a remote document.  The *messages* aren't specific to "list of favorite authors"; as far as the machines are concerned, it's just another document.

Using POST instead of PUT is *fine* -- when the world wide web began, all unsafe messages were POST, and that was catastrophically successful.  [It is OK to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).