# Should I use GET or POST or PUT in rest api to get output based on few input params which are to be accepted as part of request body

Tags: rest, microservices

I am writing a rest api which will provide some information based on the inputs in the request body. I am a bit confused which http method should I use i.e GET or PUT or POST.
As I know there will be request body so I am ruling out GET from this, as I did some research and found few server implementations may ignore request body for GET.
Now , the question remains should I use POST or PUT.
Considering the output of the API will remain same for same input provided (eg: if input is 1 and output is true, output will always remain true for input 1) which means the method should be idempotent, I am leaning more towards using PUT as compared to POST. Just want to confirm if I am thinking in the right direction.
Would be grateful for any help provided over this.

Comment: `POST` is intended to create a new resource, `PUT` is is intended to mainly update a resource but the API may decide to also create it if it doesn't exist. `GET` is intended to retrieve resources. `GET ` also should not change state of a resource. More info [**here**](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/) - When you found what fits your requirement best then look how you will have to send the parameters along with the request as some prefer one method over another.

Answer (score 1):

GET request should not have a request body in HTTP/1.1, more reading:
[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

PUT as the name suggests puts a resource somewhere, so it's not the request to choose either.

POST is what I would choose to do something like that.

Or you could parse the data into the URL for GET.

(More reading: [What's the difference between a POST and a PUT HTTP REQUEST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request))

(It's one of my first answers - please leave feedback so I could improve!)

Comment: I agree, I would also use either POST or convert the data to URL query parameters and use GET. An example where I use query parameters would be filling in a search form and on submit convert the data to query parameters and then use GET to get the result.

Comment: Hello Janko and Beyers ,thanks for you time and answers, but still one question comes to my mind and that is should we not think about idempotency over here ?

Comment: Is the operation changing resource(s)? If not, then I would say GET is more appropriate than POST/PUT. If it is changing resource(s) and idempotent then PUT is more accurate from a REST purest point of view. I'm no REST purest and try to keep things as simple as possible: GET for no changes, POST for new resource, PUT to update resource, DELETE to delete resource. I would argue documenting the API usage is more important than sticking to strict REST rules...