# There is a real difference in GET, DELETE, POST in express router?

Tags: node.js, express, rest, express-router

When we write a express server we can set the routes using GET, POST, DELETE, PUT.

There is a real difference between then? Or is just a "best practice" thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a POST and a PUT HTTP REQUEST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are real differences. You should follow the HTTP spec when using Express or any other web server.

> [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) requests a representation of the specified resource
>
> [`DELETE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE) deletes the specified resource
>
> [`POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) sends data to the server