# UPDATE CRUD operation in C# restful webservice

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, crud

I have been asked to implement an UPDATE operation in C# but the only attributes available are:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpDeleteAttribute

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGetAttribute

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpHeadAttribute

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpOptionsAttribute

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPatchAttribute

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPutAttribute

Which is the best method alternative to implement an UPDATE operation?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPutAttribute

This will Create/Update an entity