# Sending image over UnityWebRequest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cmd

I am trying to send an image over to the server via Unity. I am able to achieve sending image via command prompt with the below code:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token 555myToken555" -F "id=Image01" -F "image=@/home/example.png" https://mywebsite.com
```

But the same way I cannot achieve using Unity's Web Request. Where do I provide the "id=Image01" and http link? Also is Put() better in performance than Post()?

```
public Texture2D tex;

UnityWebRequest unityWebRequest= UnityWebRequest.Put( tex,  texture.EncodeToPNG());

unityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token 555myToken555");

unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the first parameter of [`UnityWebRequest.Put`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Put.html) is not your `tex` where the [`ToString`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.ToString.html) implicitly returns [`tex.name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html) but rather the **URI**!

And then note that [`curl -F`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)

> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. **This causes curl to POST data** using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc

This anyway uses **POST**, not **PUT**.

And in a [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) you can easily add form parts using e.g. a [`WWWForm`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) and [`AddField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddField.html) and [`AddBinaryData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddBinaryData.html) like e.g.

```
public void UploadTexture(Texture2D tex)
{
    StartCoroutine(UploadTextureRoutine(tex));
}

private IEnumerator UploadTextureRoutine(Texture2D tex)
{
    var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    var form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("id", "Image01");
    form.AddBinaryData("image", bytes, $"{tex.name}.png", "image/png");
    
    using(var unityWebRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://mywebsite.com", form))
    {
        unityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token 555myToken555");
    
        yield return unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();
    
        if (unityWebRequest.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) 
        {
            print($"Failed to upload {tex.name}: {unityWebRequest.result} - {unityWebRequest.error}");
        }
        else 
        {
            print($"Finished Uploading {tex.name}");
        }
    }
}
```

---

> Also is Put() better in performance than Post()

They are [Completely different Protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request).

Comment: Hey thanks alot for the detailed explanation :) I have used your code but I am getting few errors. I am assigning the texture png in the inspector and this texture is Read/Write enabled. But still I get the following erros: ```Unsupported texture format - Texture2D::EncodeTo functions do not support compressed texture formats.``` and ```UnassignedReferenceException: The variable tex of MyScript has not been assigned.```

Comment: I anyway wanted to send a screenshot of the screen so I made a workaround for that with your code.:)